# rsync --files-from and protect filter does not work

Tags: rsync

I'm using rsync with '--files-from' and I would like to exclude ONE of the pathes in this list to be 'protected' by a filter, but it seems it will not work.

This is my setup:

Content of /backuplist.txt file:

```
path1
path2/and/more
```

The rsync command is like this:

```
rsync -aHr --filter "protect path1/*" $dry --progress --delete --force --inplace --delete-after --files-from=/backuplist.txt /source /target
```

What I want is to copy files recursively from '/source/path1' and '/source/path2/and/more' into '/target/path1' and '/target/path2/and/more'. Everything non-existing in the source paths existing in the target paths should be deleted EXCEPT any files within '/target/path1' an below(!)

I tried the following filter which did not work:

```
--filter "protect path1/*"
--filter "protect path1/"
--filter "protect path1"
--filter "protect /path1"
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: i find the name '/target/source/path1' confusing. which is it, source or target?

Comment: sorry for the typo. It's /target/path1 of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the input, but after reading and testing around, I found the solution for it:

instead of this:

```
--filter "protect path1/*"
```

it has to be:

```
--filter "protect path1/**/*"
```

and it works like a charm in one rsync call.

Comment: from  https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync#Filter%20Rules - a trailing `dir_name/***` will match both the directory (as if `dir_name/` had been specified) and everything in the directory (as if `dir_name/**` had been specified). This behavior was added in version 2.6.7.